# Setting a particular view on top in ScrollView programmatically

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview

I want to get result image pragmatically.

When the user submitted answer the view "Option" text should automatically set on top of the screen in `ScrollView`. The whole view is inside the `ScrollView`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: there is a view above the "Option" text.

Comment: Please paste some code of what you have done, also the question is not very clear, like how you want the view to be,like only text or whole layout or what

Answer (score 0):

You might have the "Option" `TextView` inside the `ScrollView` with a visibility set to `gone` in your layout XML file. When an answer is selected, change the visibility status of that `TextView` to `View.VISIBLE` programmatically.

Hope that is clear. Please let me know if you need to anything else.